# Unable to get counter to count digits, upper and lower case in a character string using pointers

Tags: c

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.. the question requires you to create a function which counts the number of uppercase and lowercase letters in a c string given.

```
char buffer1[] = "Hello Programming 1 Students";

int upper_count = 0;
int lower_count = 0;
int digit_count = 0;

count_categories(buffer1, &upper_count, &lower_count, &digit_count);

printf("[%s] upper: %d, lower: %d, digit: %d\n", buffer1, upper_count, lower_count, digit_count);


void count_categories(char* p_cstring, int* p_upper_count, int* p_lower_count, int* p_digit_count)
{
for (int k = 0; k!= '\0'; k++)
{
    if ((p_cstring[k] >= 'A') && (p_cstring[k] <= 'Z'))
    {
        p_upper_count++;
    }

    if ((p_cstring[k] >= 'a') && (p_cstring[k] <= 'z'))
    {
        p_lower_count++;
    }
    if ((p_cstring[k] >= '0') && (p_cstring[k] <= '9'));
    {
        p_digit_count++;
    }
}
}
```

I'm calling it using

```
count_categories(buffer1, &upper_count, &lower_count, &digit_count);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer to modify the data it points at.  Right now, you're just incrementing the pointer itself (to point at the next integer-sized memory location, as if it were an array).

Change the increments as follows:

```
(*p_upper_count)++;
```

Same for your other counts.

You also have an issue with the termination condition in your loop.  Currently it is `k != '\0'` which will immediately stop the loop before any iterations.  You need to be testing the actual string contents at position `k`:

```
for (int k = 0; p_cstring[k] != '\0'; k++)
```

Comment: Changed it, still no luck.

Comment: Uhh.. Did you change them _all_?  And did you recompile your program before running it?

Comment: Oh, I see another issue.  `k != '\0'` is not the correct termination condition for your loop.  It should be `p_cstring[k] != '\0'`

Comment: I changed p_upper_count, p_lower_count and p_digit_count. The program is running it's just showing the values all as 0.

Comment: Worked!. Thanks mate. The logic and null pointers have me really confused. Is it always this tricky early on with pointers?

Comment: You're welcome.  I highly recommend reading this post about debugging: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- the sooner you learn debugging techniques, the more proficient you will become at writing working programs.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi: If the solution has worked for you, then you should accept this as an answer by clicking the 'check' icon.

Comment: Many beginners struggle with pointers.  I have never understood why that is.  All you need to remember is that a pointer is a _number_ that tells you where something is in memory.  It also has a _type_, which tells you what kind of thing that memory holds.  That's all.  If in doubt, write down on paper with boxes to represent memory locations, including memory holding the pointer value itself, and use arrows to show where the pointer is pointing.

Comment: It's not appropriate to springboard from one answer to a new question about another problem.  I suggest you read and digest that information about debugging I linked above.  Then try it out on your new problem.  If you cannot figure it out after an hour, then post a _new_ question on Stack Overflow.  There really is no point just asking for help whenever something doesn't work the way you expected.  You will not learn to code that way.

Comment: Yes, I got it sorted after reflecting on the problem and set upper,lower and digits to 0 before starting the loop in the function.

Comment: Excellent.  Make _reflection_ part of your natural response, and you'll go far! :)  Hollywood makes programming look like it's just hammering code into a terminal and achieving wonderful things.  That's _not_ reality.  Writing code is actually a pretty small percentage of what a programmer does.